# CSS: Fix positioning of input in Log-In form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying fix the Log-In & registration form. When you click on "Register"  on my menu, you can see that the labels are perfectly formatted in the form but the input box are offset. I tried to fix it with float:left but it didn't work out too well. If somebody could help me with that, that would be awesome.

```js
var popup = document.getElementById('id01');
var popupreg = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == popup) {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == popupreg) {
    popupreg.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

div.container {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
}

a.nounderline span {
  color: #00B200;
}

.main-menu {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 26px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 35%;
}

.floating-sidebar li {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.floating-sidebar li a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444950;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.floating-sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.floating-sidebar li a.active {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #00B200;
}

.floating-sidebar:hover li a.register-link {
  color: #b5e7a0;
  background: #fff;
}

.floating-sidebar li a.active:hover {
  background-color: #00B200;
  color: #fff;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: left;
  padding: 4.5px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  width: 305px;
  border: 2px solid #00B200;
  border-radius: 18px;
  outline: inherit;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  direction: inherit;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #BEBEBE;
}

span.topnav {
  right: 50px;
}

.sortby-box {
  padding-top: 124px;
  padding-left: 44;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
}

.select-opt {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #00B200;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.select-opt option {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup,
.popupreg {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.popup-content,
.popupreg-content {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 39px;
  left: 666px;
  top: 210px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(109, 196, 109);
}

.popup,
.popupreg label {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.popup [type=text],
[type=password] {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popupreg [type=text],
[type=password] {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup input[type=submit] {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
}

.popupreg input[type=submit] {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
}

.popup [type=submit] {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00B200;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 180px;
  margin-left: 88px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
}

.popupreg [type=submit] {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00B200;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 180px;
  margin-left: 88px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
}

.popup .submit-log:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00B200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popupreg .submit-log:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00B200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cancel {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.username-section,
.reg-section {
  padding: 32px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

span.psswrd {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">Hello</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>

  <aside>
  </aside>
</main>
<sidebar>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="floating-sidebar">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active register-link" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Language</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</sidebar>
<div class="sortby-box">
  <select class="select-opt">
    <option>Newest</option>
    <option>Popularity</option>
    <option>Recommended</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="topnav">
  <input style="position:relative;" type="text" name: "searchText" placeholder="Search here.." maxlength="18">
  <span style="position:absolute; left: 126px; top: 119px;" class="fa fa-search icon"></span>
</div>
<div id="id01" class="popup">
  <form class="popup-content" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <div class="cancel">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="username-section">
      <label for="usrname">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="usrname" name="usrname" minlength="6" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      <label for="psswrd">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="psswrd" minlength="6" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" class="submit-log" value="Log In">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="id02" class="popupreg">
  <form class="popupreg-content" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <div class="cancel">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="reg-section">
      <label for="usrname">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="usrname" name="usrname" minlength="6" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      <label for="usrname">Mail</label>
      <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" minlength="6" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      <label for="psswrd">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="psswrd" minlength="6" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" class="submit-log" value="Register">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the input boxes aren't in the same column. i.e. one directly above/below the other?

Comment: exactly! I need to align them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix would be to give the label elements a `display: inline-block;` and give them a defined width such as `width: 100px;`.

I quickly created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koder613/y5novf1s/3/) to illustrate.

Hope this helped.